# How to play short sounds on c++ android app?

Tags: android, c++, audio, android-ndk

I'm trying to play sound files on my C++ Android app.

All the options that I've found are for C++ on Windows, the only one that I've tried is this, but it isn't working.

```
#include <SimpleAudioEngine.h>

auto audio = CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance();

const char *sound = "Sound1.wav";

audio->preloadEffect(sound);
audio->playEffect(sound);
```

Comment: Its probably not this but, you forgot a semi-colon on *sound line. Do not want users to think that is the problem.

Comment: @coletrain that's not the problem, because this code work perfect when i run on ios device, the semi-colon i just forget put it when i asked the question, but thank you for your comment, i already asked 3 question about this and anybody answer, i hear any suggestion

Comment: The easiest solution is to use JNI to get SoundPool play your files.